# rounded edges for cells of cell renderer Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have used cell Renderer to display data in table format with entries displayed in each cell in java swing.
I have also got to put the desired color for each cell.

I there a way I can change the look of the cell? What I want is there a way I can have curved edges for each cell in the table?

Answer (score 2):

The responsibility would fall to the `TableCellRenderer`, so you'd have to set the border up in the renderers.

You would also have to turn off the grid drawing, using [`JTable#setShowGrid`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setShowGrid%28boolean%29)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint. I will try it out. WIll derive some solution. Thanks again. I have upvoted your answer